# polyglossia (with XeTeX) warning: File gloss-latex.ldf does not exist!

Tags: xetex, polyglossia

I'm using

- XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022)
- kpathsea version 6.3.4

to compile

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{de}

\begin{document}
 Test
\end{document}
```

I get two warnings:

```
Package polyglossia Warning: File gloss-latex.ldf does not exist!
(polyglossia)                I will nevertheless try to use hyphenation pattern
s for latex. on input line 2549.


Package polyglossia Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for `latex'
(polyglossia)                I will use \language=\l@nohyphenation instead on i
nput line 2549.
```

What happened? What can I do to avoid these warnings?

Complete log

```
*****
*****     XeLaTeX Ausgabe: 
*****     cd "/home/ro/Schreibtisch/wegtex"
*****     xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 -enable-write18 test.tex
*****
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script document class (article)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile-hook.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlogo.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xltxtra/xltxtra.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
(|extractbb --version))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/realscripts/realscripts.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/metalogo/metalogo.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/polyglossia.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecmds/makecmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)

Package polyglossia Warning: File gloss-latex.ldf does not exist!
(polyglossia)                I will nevertheless try to use hyphenation pattern
s for latex. on input line 2549.


Package polyglossia Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for `latex'
(polyglossia)                I will use \language=\l@nohyphenation instead on i
nput line 2549.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-de.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-german.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/babelsh.def)))
(./test.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
[1] (./test.aux) )
Output written on test.pdf (1 page).
SyncTeX written on test.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Comment: looks like a bug to me. Report it here https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/. Unrelated but I wouldn't use xltxtra  anymore, that is rather outdated and no longer recommended.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug, the developer is informed: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/537